# MFC Dragging Objects

Tags: c++, mfc

I painted three objects onto a window using `CPaintDC`, and now I am trying to get one of them (the ellipse) to become draggable by using `OnMouseMove` event handler.  I am just playing around with MFC and am lost as to how to get this to work.

This is what I have tried in `OnMouseMove`:

```
// TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default
CClientDC dc(this);
CRect rect;
GetClientRect(&rect);
dc.SetMapMode(MM_ANISOTROPIC);
dc.SetWindowExt(100, 100);
CRect rectEllipse(ellipse.cx, ellipse.cy,(ellipse.cx) + 10, (ellipse.cy) + 10);//(10, 10, 20, 20);dc.Ellipse(ellipse.cx, ellipse.cy, (ellipse.cx) + 10, (ellipse.cy) + 10);//10, 10, 20, 20);
//CPoint ellipseDest;

//dc.SetViewportExt(rect.Width(), rect.Height());
 if (mouseCaptured)
   {
       ellipse.cx = point.x;
       ellipse.cy = point.y;
       InvalidateRect(rectEllipse, TRUE); 
   }
CDialogEx::OnMouseMove(nFlags, point);
```

Please find my code pasted below.

Thanks so much for the help.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CSIT861a3 Vasilkovskiy.h"
#include "CSIT861a3 VasilkovskiyDlg.h"
#include "afxdialogex.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif


// CAboutDlg dialog used for App About

class CAboutDlg : public CDialogEx
{
public:
    CAboutDlg();

// Dialog Data
    enum { IDD = IDD_ABOUTBOX };

    protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support

// Implementation
protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
public:
//  afx_msg void OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point);
//  afx_msg void OnLButtonUp(UINT nFlags, CPoint point);
//  afx_msg void OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point);
};

CAboutDlg::CAboutDlg() : CDialogEx(CAboutDlg::IDD)
{
}

void CAboutDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CAboutDlg, CDialogEx)
//  ON_WM_LBUTTONDOWN()
//  ON_WM_LBUTTONUP()
//  ON_WM_MOUSEMOVE()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// CCSIT861a3VasilkovskiyDlg dialog




CCSIT861a3VasilkovskiyDlg::CCSIT861a3VasilkovskiyDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialogEx(CCSIT861a3VasilkovskiyDlg::IDD, pParent)
{
    m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);

    ellipseColor = RGB(255, 0, 0);
    centerRectColor = RGB(0, 0, 0);
    rightRectColor = RGB(255, 0, 0);
    centerRect.left = 40;
    centerRect.top = 20;
    centerRect.right = 55;
    centerRect.bottom = 80;
    rightRect.left = 75;
    rightRect.top = 35;
    rightRect.right = 90;
    rightRect.bottom = 50;
    ellipse.cx = 10;
    ellipse.cy = 10;
    mouseCaptured = false;
}

void CCSIT861a3VasilkovskiyDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CCSIT861a3VasilkovskiyDlg, CDialogEx)
    ON_WM_SYSCOMMAND()
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()
    ON_WM_LBUTTONDOWN()
    ON_WM_LBUTTONUP()
    ON_WM_MOUSEMOVE()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// CCSIT861a3VasilkovskiyDlg message handlers

BOOL CCSIT861a3VasilkovskiyDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

    // Add "About..." menu item to system menu.

    // IDM_ABOUTBOX must be in the system command range.
    ASSERT((IDM_ABOUTBOX & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX);
    ASSERT(IDM_ABOUTBOX < 0xF000);

    CMenu* pSysMenu = GetSystemMenu(FALSE);
    if (pSysMenu != NULL)
    {
        BOOL bNameValid;
        CString strAboutMenu;
        bNameValid = strAboutMenu.LoadString(IDS_ABOUTBOX);
        ASSERT(bNameValid);
        if (!strAboutMenu.IsEmpty())
        {
            pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_SEPARATOR);
            pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_STRING, IDM_ABOUTBOX, strAboutMenu);
        }
    }

    // Set the icon for this dialog.  The framework does this automatically
    //  when the application's main window is not a dialog
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE);         // Set big icon
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE);        // Set small icon

    // TODO: Add extra initialization here

    return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}

void CCSIT861a3VasilkovskiyDlg::OnSysCommand(UINT nID, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if ((nID & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX)
    {
        CAboutDlg dlgAbout;
        dlgAbout.DoModal();
    }
    else
    {
        CDialogEx::OnSysCommand(nID, lParam);
    }
}

// If you add a minimize button to your dialog, you will need the code below
//  to draw the icon.  For MFC applications using the document/view model,
//  this is automatically done for you by the framework.

void CCSIT861a3VasilkovskiyDlg::OnPaint()
{
    //Create pen and pointer to the old pen
    CPen blackPen; 
    blackPen.CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, RGB (0, 0, 0)); 

    //Create a bursh
    CBrush blackBrush(centerRectColor);
    CBrush redBrush(rightRectColor);
    CBrush hatchRedBrush(HS_CROSS, ellipseColor);

    //Set up object for painting
    CPaintDC dc (this);
    CRect rect;
    GetClientRect (&rect);
    dc.SetMapMode (MM_ANISOTROPIC);
    dc.SetWindowExt (100, 100);
    dc.SetViewportExt (rect.Width (), rect.Height ());


    //select pen 
    dc.SelectObject(&blackPen);

    //Rectangle red interior color
    dc.SelectObject(&redBrush);
    dc.Rectangle(rightRect); //(75, 35, 90, 50);

    //Rectangel black interior
    dc.SelectObject(&blackBrush);//Select Brush
    dc.Rectangle( centerRect);//(40, 20, 55, 80);

    //Ellipse
    dc.SelectObject(&hatchRedBrush);//Select Brush
    dc.Ellipse(ellipse.cx, ellipse.cy, (ellipse.cx) + 10, (ellipse.cy) + 10);//10, 10, 20, 20);

    if (IsIconic())
    {
        CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

        SendMessage(WM_ICONERASEBKGND, reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(dc.GetSafeHdc()), 0);

        // Center icon in client rectangle
        int cxIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON);
        int cyIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON);
        CRect rect;
        GetClientRect(&rect);
        int x = (rect.Width() - cxIcon + 1) / 2;
        int y = (rect.Height() - cyIcon + 1) / 2;

        // Draw the icon
        dc.DrawIcon(x, y, m_hIcon);
    }
    else
    {
        CDialogEx::OnPaint();
    }
}

// The system calls this function to obtain the cursor to display while the user drags
//  the minimized window.
HCURSOR CCSIT861a3VasilkovskiyDlg::OnQueryDragIcon()
{
    return static_cast<HCURSOR>(m_hIcon);
}



//void CAboutDlg::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
//{
//  // TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default
//  //SetCapture();
//  CClientDC dc(this);
//  CRect rect;
//  GetClientRect(&rect);
//  dc.SetMapMode(MM_ANISOTROPIC);
//  dc.SetWindowExt(100, 100);
//  dc.SetViewportExt(rect.Width(), rect.Height());
//  CRect rectEllipse(10, 10, 20, 20);
//  
//  ellipseColor = RGB(0,0,0);
//
//  CDialogEx::OnLButtonDown(nFlags, point);
//}


//void CAboutDlg::OnLButtonUp(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
//{
//  // TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default
//  ReleaseCapture ();
//  CDialogEx::OnLButtonUp(nFlags, point);
//}


//void CAboutDlg::OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
//{
//  // TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default
//
//  CDialogEx::OnMouseMove(nFlags, point);
//}


void CCSIT861a3VasilkovskiyDlg::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    // TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default


    CClientDC dc(this);
    CRect rect;
    GetClientRect(&rect);
    dc.SetMapMode(MM_ANISOTROPIC);
    dc.SetWindowExt(100, 100);
    dc.SetViewportExt(rect.Width(), rect.Height());

    CRect rectEllipse(ellipse.cx, ellipse.cy, 20, 20);//(10, 10, 20, 20);
    CRgn circle;
    dc.LPtoDP(rectEllipse); 
    circle.CreateEllipticRgnIndirect(rectEllipse);

    if (circle.PtInRegion(point))
    {
        SetCapture();
            mouseCaptured = true;
        ellipseColor = RGB(0,0,255);
        InvalidateRect(rectEllipse, FALSE);
    }

    CDialogEx::OnLButtonDown(nFlags, point);
}


void CCSIT861a3VasilkovskiyDlg::OnLButtonUp(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    // TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default
    ReleaseCapture ();
    mouseCaptured = false;
    CDialogEx::OnLButtonUp(nFlags, point);
}


void CCSIT861a3VasilkovskiyDlg::OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{

    // TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default

     if (mouseCaptured)
       {
              /*
                Code to drag and drop and redraw ellipse
                  */
              InvalidateRect(rectEllipse, TRUE); 
       }
    CDialogEx::OnMouseMove(nFlags, point);
}
```

Comment: You need to invalidate two rectangles, one at the old position and one at the new position. Or make a single rectangle large enough to include both.

Comment: Just be careful with MFC. Sure it works, but if you can, look elsewhere.

Comment: @MarkRansom Currently my when I try to drag the ellipse it simply erases part of it. Shouldn't it print multiple new ones without erasing the old ones if this was the problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Mark Ransom's comment is right, you need to invalidate two rectangles on MouseMove.

```
CRect rectEllipse(ellipse.cx, ellipse.cy,(ellipse.cx) + 10, (ellipse.cy) + 10);
if (mouseCaptured)
{    InvalidateRect(rectEllipse, TRUE); 
     ellipse.cx = point.x;
     ellipse.cy = point.y;
     CRect rectNew(ellipse.cx, ellipse.cy,(ellipse.cx) + 10, (ellipse.cy) + 10);
     InvalidateRect(rectNew, TRUE);
```

}

Also, on `OnLButtonUp()`

```
if (mouseCaptured)
{    ellipseColor = RGB(255, 0, 0);
     CRect rectEllipse(ellipse.cx, ellipse.cy,(ellipse.cx) + 10, (ellipse.cy) + 10);
     InvalidateRect(rectEllipse, TRUE); 
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but the problem is the same.  All that happens when the left mouse button is pressed over the ellipse is the ellipse is erased in the location where the mouse is pressed.

Comment: could you try moving your custom paint logic in `OnPaint()` to after the call to `CDialogEx::OnPaint()`?